# MVC - how to get webgrid textbox values after click submit button?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, textbox, webgrid

I wonder how I can pass textbox values (webgrid textbox column) to Controller when clicking button? I have tried several solutions but it never worked for me.

My code example will help me understand. Thanks!

**Index.cshtml**

```
var grid = new WebGrid(Model, 
                       defaultSort: "Number", 
                       rowsPerPage: 10, 
                       ajaxUpdateContainerId: "searchResults");

@grid.GetHtml(mode: WebGridPagerModes.All,
              htmlAttributes: new { id = "searchResults" },
              columns: new[] {
                         grid.Column("Id"),
                         grid.Column("Date"),
                         grid.Column("Status"),
                         grid.Column("Reason", format:(item) => Html.TextBox("Reason", (object) item.Reason))
             });

<input id="IDSubmit" type="submit" value="Submit"  />
```